# Play avi videos in google chrome

Tags: html, python-2.7, google-chrome, opencv, django-templates

How to to play avi videos in chrome?

My code is

```
<center><video width="560" height="448" controls>
  <source src="plaque.avi" type="video/avi"> </source>
</video></center>
```

but I can see only the player inactive and no video image.

Any help please?

Comment: you can only use .ogg or .mp4 in the html5 video tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5  tag does **not** support .avi format.

Your best chance it to convert it to mp4, webm or some other web applicable format.

Comment: I'm doing some video processing using python/opencv and `cv2.VideoCapture()` method can read only avi video.

Comment: @zinon you could probably use [python-video-converter](https://github.com/senko/python-video-converter) within your program.

Comment: I will search it out. Thank you.